# Monitoring the OnPremise network appliances from Azure?

Tags: azure, monitoring, network-monitoring, azure-networking, system-monitoring

People,

I have the need to monitor the OnPremise Network appliances (Gateways, Firewalls and other services IP addresses) from Azure, then send an email alert or trigger alert via PagerDuty.
https://www.pagerduty.com/platform/ when offline.

The ExpressRoute circuit from my Data centre to Azure Regional data centre has been established so my Laptop can ping Azure VM I deployed.

However, as per this documentation https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/agents-overview document I cannot find any way to monitor just a few select IP addresses of network appliances, since it requires Agent install.

I also cannot configure Pingdom service to test my network appliances IP address either.
https://tools.pingdom.com/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only on-premises resources that Azure Monitor supports are those that can run the agent, so mainly VM's and Kubernetes.

If you can configure your resources to send data to a Log Analytics workspace you could potentially use that as a heartbeat type monitor, but I suspect your devices won't be able to do that.